# NodeJS. Can I handle errors in one place? Without try and catch blocks

Tags: node.js, error-handling, async-await

Node said that I should catch errors on all my promises.

Does exist a good practice for handling the same errors in one function? 
I don't want to write always the same catch block for all requests.

My code looks like:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await makeRequest()    
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
makeRequest()
    .catch(err => {
        // console.error(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For `async` IIFE (IIAFE) error handling is performed as:

```
(async () => {
  await makeRequest()    
})().catch(console.error);
```

Notice that in Node.js `console` methods are bound to proper context, so they can be passed as callbacks.